# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent Normal variables each with mean zero, then $\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ is also a Normal variable

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, random-variable

I am trying to prove the statement:

> If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_2^2)$ are independent random variables,
>
> then $\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ is also a Normal random variable.

For the special case $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$ (say), we have the well-known result that $\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{4}\right)$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ variables. In fact, it is more generally known that $\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}},\frac{X^2-Y^2}{2\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ are independent $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{4}\right)$ variables.

A proof of the last result follows by using the transformation $(X,Y)\to(R,\Theta)\to(U,V)$ where $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and $u=\frac{r}{2}\sin(2\theta),v=\frac{r}{2}\cos(2\theta)$. Indeed, here $U=\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ and $V=\frac{X^2-Y^2}{2\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$. I tried to imitate this proof for the problem at hand but it appears to get messy.

If I haven't made any error, then for $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ I end up with the joint density of $(U,V)$ as

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{2}{\sigma_1\sigma_2\pi}\exp\left[-\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}+v}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}-v}{\sigma_2^2}\right)\right]$$

I have the multiplier $2$ above as the transformation is not one-to-one.

So density of $U$ would be given by $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{U,V}(u,v)\,\mathrm{d}v$, which isn't readily evaluated.

Now I am interested to know if there is a proof where I can only work with $U$ and don't have to consider some $V$ to show that $U$ is Normal. Finding the CDF of $U$ doesn't look so promising to me at the moment. I would also like to do the same for the case $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$.

That is, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ variables then I wish to show that $Z=\frac{2XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ without using a change of variables. If somehow I can argue that $Z\stackrel{d}{=}X$, then I'm done. So two questions here, the general case and then the particular case.

Related posts on Math.S.E:

[$X^2-Y^2/ \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}\sim N(0,1)$ when $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ independently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503285/is-x2-y2-sqrtx2y2-normal-where-x-y-sim-n0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

[Given that $X,Y$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ , show that $\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}},\frac{X^2-Y^2}{2\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ are i.i.d. $N(0,\frac{1}{4})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647442/given-that-x-y-are-independent-n0-1-show-that-fracxy-sqrtx2y2).

**Edit.**

This problem is in fact due to L. Shepp as I found out in the exercises of *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications* (Vol. II) by Feller, alongwith a possible hint:

[image]

Surely, $U=\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{X^2}+\frac{1}{Y^2}}}$ and I have the density of $\frac{1}{X^2}$ at hand.

Let's see what I could do now. Apart from this, a little help with the integral above is also welcome.

Comment: While similar, the MGF approach for the joint $(U,V)$ is a bit easier. See the last answer of: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2665178/22064

and:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664469/computing-iint-mathbb-r2-exp-leftu-fracxy-sqrtx2y2v-fracx2-y/2664848#2664848

Comment: @AlexR. Yes I had seen the joint mgf approach, which works quite well if I am to find the joint distribution for the equal variance case. But I already have the proof by change of variables in that case, which in my mind is easier. What I am trying to do is to work with $U$ alone, since that is the distribution I am after.

Comment: The trick is that the sum of $\frac{1}{X^2}$ and $\frac{1}{Y^2}$, which are scaled inverse chi-squared distributions, is also a scaled inverse chi-squared distribution (that is the property of stable distributions). So the magic happens in the third equation of the following:

$$U = \frac{XY}{X^2+Y^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{X^2}+\frac{1}{Y^2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{Z^2}}} = Z$$

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Apparently that is the original proof given by Shepp.

Comment: I would not have come up with this myself if you hadn't mentioned the commentary by Shepp. But, I had the idea that you did not get this proof. Or at least this was unclear whether this was the case.

Comment: Regarding your straightforward integration it is eventually a bit cumbersome like integrating $\sqrt{r^2-x^2} dx$ to obtain the area of a circle.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings  You are right the theory of this proof isn't something I am familiar with.

Comment: Another related post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2021096/321264.

Answer (score 6):

The original solution of the problem by Shepp uses the concept of stable law property, which seems a bit advanced for me at the moment. So I could not comprehend the hint given in the exercise I cited in my post. I guess a proof involving only the single variable $U=\frac{XY}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$ and not using a change of variables is difficult to come up with. So I share three open access papers I found that provide an alternate solution to the problem:

- [A note on Normal functions of Normal random variables](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122181901243)
- [Normal functions of Normal random variables](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122187901477)
- [A Result of Shepp](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893965994900892)

The first one has convinced me not to go down the integration path I took with that choice of the variable $V$ to derive the density of $U$. It is the third paper that looks like something I can follow. I give a brief sketch of the proof here:

We assume without loss of generality $\sigma_1^2=1$, and set $\sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$. Now noting that $X^2\sim\chi^2_1$ and $\frac{Y^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_1$ are independent, we have the joint density of $(X^2,Y^2)$. We denote it by $f_{X^2,Y^2}$.

Consider the transformation $(X^2,Y^2)\to(W,Z)$ such that $W=\frac{X^2Y^2}{X^2+Y^2}$ and $Z=\frac{X^2+Y^2}{Y^2}$. So we have the joint density of $(W,Z)$. Let us denote it by $f_{W,Z}$. Following the standard procedure, we integrate $f_{W,Z}$ wrt to $z$ to get the marginal density $f_W$ of $W$.

We find that $W=U^2$ is a Gamma variate with parameters $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2(1+\frac{1}{\sigma})^{-2}$, so that $(1+\frac{1}{\sigma})^2\,W\sim\chi^2_1$. We note that the density of $U$ is symmetric about $0$. This implies that $(1+\frac{1}{\sigma})U\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and hence $U\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\left(\frac{\sigma}{\sigma+1}\right)^2\right)$.