# $V=XY/\sqrt{(X^2+Y^2)}$ Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

If $X$ and $Y$ are iid N(0,1) what is the pdf of $V=XY/\sqrt{(X^2+Y^2)}$.

I have found out the distribution of $1/(X^2)$. So will that be any useful and if yes how ?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: See the links in this post :https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/333295/119261.